# How to prevent Sophos HitmanPro, Sophos Endpoint Defence, and Windows Defender High CPU with Visual Studio Code GIT operations

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, windows-defender, sophos

For a little over a week now I have been having high CPU usage issues by **Sophos HitmanPro.Alert**, **Sophos Endpoint Defence** and **Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection Service** when performing GIT operations in **Visual Studio Code** on **Windows 10**.

I have the following GIT-related **extensions** installed in **Visual Studio Code**:

- Gitflow Actions Sidebar
- GitLens

The issue happens when I do any of the following GIT operations:

- Fetch
- Pull
- Compare Changes
- Commit
- Push or Synch

It is making a sub 5 second operation into up to 30 seconds at times.

Here is one occasion captured from TaskManager

[image]

...and from another occasion

[image]

The folder location of the project code has already been **added into the Sophos exclusions**.

Is there another folder location I need to request added to the Sophos exclusions? Maybe a temporary folder where GIT or VS writes files ready for GIT operations?

Is there anything else which can be configured for **Sophos** or **Windows Defender** when using **Visual Studio Code** and GIT?

**EDIT 1:**
I have tried disabling both of the two states extensions and that does not make any difference.

**EDIT 2:**
I have just discovered this morning that this issue **does not appear to happen when the remote repo is a BitBucket repo**, *only for an Azure Dev Ops repo*.

Comment: Have you tried creating an exception on the folder that contains your project?  You have a lot of security scanning files, you already know, are secure and not malware.

Comment: @Ramhound - As per the statement in my post -> "The folder location of the project code has already been added into the Sophos exclusions." ??? If so, then yes.

Comment: Getting the impression you might not be an Administrator on the machine but have you also added the exclusion for Windows Defender Advanced Threat? I do admit I didn’t see that particular statement in your question during my original reading of it

Comment: @Ramhound - Although I am a local admin, the AV rules are handled by our IT dept. and are not overridable. I raised a ticket for the exclusion, and it was actioned. although I am not entirely sure of they have added to WD exclusions as well as Sophos, or not.

I do have a slight update to the post which I will add as EDIT 2